# DataTable: server side - TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Tags: jquery, database, datatable, datatables, loading

I'm converting my json script to server side script to draw a table because i started using DataTable when I had 500 data, but now I have more than 1000 data.

I'm following this tutorial https://coderexample.com/datatable-demo-server-side-in-phpmysql-and-ajax/ but i receive the error: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined".

What's wrong? I'm so sorry but I'm a newbie.

**search_user.php**

```
if ($type=="search"){
    $requestData= $_REQUEST;
    $columns = array(
        0 =>'id',
        1 =>'email',
        2 =>'nome',
        3 =>'cognome',
        4 =>'lingua',
        5 =>'unsubscribe'
    );
    $sql = "SELECT id,email,nome,cognome,lingua,unsubscribe FROM newsletter_utenti";
    $query=mysqli_query($db, $sql) or die();
    $totalData = mysqli_num_rows($query);
    $totalFiltered = $totalData;

    $data = array();
    while( $row=mysqli_fetch_array($query) ) {
        $nestedData=array();
        $nestedData[] = $row["id"];
        $nestedData[] = $row["email"];
        $nestedData[] = $row["nome"];
        $nestedData[] = $row["cognome"];
        $nestedData[] = $row["lingua"];
        $nestedData[] = $row["unsubscribe"];
        $data[] = $nestedData;
    }
    $json_data = array(
                "draw"            => intval( $requestData['draw'] ),
                "recordsTotal"    => intval( $totalData ),
                "recordsFiltered" => intval( $totalFiltered ),
                "data"            => $data
                );

    echo json_encode($json_data);
}
```

**JS Script**

```
var dataTable = $('#contacts-grid').DataTable( {
    "processing": true,
    "serverSide": true,
    "ajax":{
      url : "search_user.php",
      type: "post",
      data: {type:'search'},
      error: function(){  // error handling
        alert("error");

      }
    }
  } );
```

**HTML**

```
<table class="table table-responsive filter-head" id="contacts-grid">
                  <thead>
                    <tr>
                      <th>ID</th>
                      <th>E-mail</th>
                      <th>Nome</th>
                      <th>Cognome</th>
                      <th>Lingua</th>
                      <th>Stato</th>
                    </tr>
                  </thead>
                  <tbody></tbody>
                </table>
```

Comment: I'm a newbie and i can follow some tutorials, but i've reach one error and I don't know what is the cause. I also tried the sources of the author and they works, but i can't understand where i wrong.

Comment: Can you have a look in the console to check that your json is returned?

Comment: I receive this error: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined" and I've noticed like ajax didn't receive any data

Comment: Yes, I know about the error - have you looked in the console?

Comment: The JSON is empty but the PHP script returns the following data:

{"draw":0,"recordsTotal":1,"recordsFiltered":1,"data":[["1","test@email.it","Mickey","Mouse","en","0"]]}

Comment: That IS the json.  the `draw` parameter doesn't seem right - it should be the same value that is sent in the datatables request - this is also visible in the console.

Comment: I've tried to force draw parameter to 1 but i'm get the same error

Comment: You can't force it - it must be the same as the value sent in the request.

Comment: I removed the condition $type=="search" and now it works. Thank you so much for your patience and support! :)

Answer (score 0):

I've removed the condition **$type=="search"** and now it works!